# How to Insert Data on ServerA that comes from Select Data on ServerB?

Tags: c#, database

Scenario:

I have a development SERVERA which I need to insert data from my tableA from ServerB TableA.

```
SERVERA.TableA:serialnumber = empty,partnumber=empty
```

Ex:

Database connection string1.

```
Select serialnumber,partnumber from ServerB.TableA where (serialnumber='1')
```

Then

Database connection string2

```
Insert into serialnumber,partnumber from SERVERA.TableA
```

Result:

```
SERVERA.TableA:serialnumber = 1,partnumber=2
```

Comment: And what are the issues you are having? What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Sql Server, you can use [Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28SQL.80%29.aspx) to provide the facility you need, you'd then be able to execute the following code on ServerB:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableA]
(
 SerialNumber,
 PartNumber
)
SELECT SerialNumber,
       PartNumber
FROM [ServerA].[DatabaseNameOnServerA].[dbo].[TableA]
WHERE SerialNumber = '1'
```

If you can't use linked servers, or want/need to do it in code then that's also fairly simple:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringForServerA)
{
  connection.Open();
  var query = "SELECT SerialNumber, PartNumber FROM [dbo].[TableA] WHERE SerialNumber = '1'";
  using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
  {
    var data = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(data);

    using (var connectionB = new SqlConnection(connectionStringForServerB)
    {
       var query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableA] (SerialNumber, PartNumber) VALUES (@Serial, @Part)";
       foreach(DataRow recordFromServerA in data.Rows)
       {
         using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, connectionB)
         {
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial", recordFromServerA["SerialNumber"]);
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Part", recordFromServerA["PartNumber"]);

           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

There are more efficient ways to carry out the insertion, but having the code spell out exactly what it's doing as I've done there should make it quite clear to you how it works (It is worth noting that I haven't actually run the code sample I've given, so it may need a bit of tweaking, it's also Sql Server specific).

Comment: Ooops, onother thing i need also to bulkinsert excel file to servertableA(that i accomplished using openrowset) but i need to reference it to ServerB TableA then insert it to ServerA.TableA.

Comment: That's a completley separate question, from the sounds of it! There's nothing in your original question, or my answer that has the slightest thing to do with inserting data from Excel.